# Бот для discord на python добавляет роли, но не убирает их

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Бот использует реакции и добавляет роли, но если убирать реакцию, он пишет Member not found (прикрепляю код):

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 822401200942350336:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=788080179624149002)
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=788080230182682634)
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=790238512774512660)
        else:
            role = None

        if role is not None:
            member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("Member not found")
        else:
            print("Role not found")
```

Ошибки нет, только выводит ответы, сначала done при получении роли и Member not found при удалении роли:

```
Stupid_bot присоединился к Discord!
done
Member not found
```

Comment: Хаха, вы уверены что эту переменную надо называть payload? ;)

Comment: До вашего вопроса я был уверен в этом, сейчас уже нет)

Comment: Тогда как же её нужно называть?

Comment: Да я просто пошутил, просто payload имеет другое значение

Comment: Выложите полную ошибку, а то так немного не понятно.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Я выложил ошибку

Comment: [Гляньте, вроде оно](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5867), [и вот еще](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64221473/11563491)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Нет, там ничего не подходит, есть ли какое-то другое решение?)

Comment: С интентами пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 822401200942350336:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=788080179624149002)
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=788080230182682634)
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=790238512774512660)
        else:
            role = None

        if role is not None:
            member =  utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("Member not found")
        else:
            print("Role not found")
```

Comment: Честно говоря, мне перестало вообще выводить какую-либо информацию, то есть мне не пишет ни Member not found, ни done, в общем ничего

Comment: в начале кода вставь строчку `from discord import utils`

Comment: Дело в том, что при добавлении модуля у меня всё также ничего не пишет...